# "Nr" rendered as Nr. in LibreOffice (Calc) and/or "Linux"

Tags: linux, fonts, libreoffice, locale, rendering

I created a LibreOffice spreadsheet in Windows. One cell contains the String "`Nr.`". When I open this file in Linux, "No" with superscript underlined o is displayed.

As I type this question, I guess that Linux is to blame, because in the question and the title, the same thing happens: I have to escape the N r ., otherwise I also get "Nr." (in Firefox).

How do I get rid of this undesired behavior?

[image]

Comment: Currently having the same problem in Firefox 90 on Ubuntu, without any (third-party) browser plugins, and with non-French (but also non-English) locale.

Answer (score 2):

This is called something like an “automatic replacement” (or in the case of LibreOffice, “[AutoCorrect](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/AutoCorrect)”), where a specific sequence of characters (like “--” aka. two dashes) is replaced by another one (like  “—” aka. em dash). Some replacements are based on your locale, for example “№” is a ligature representing “numéro” and similar in at least French. If the text language is French, or if it's undefined and your system language is French this replacement will happen automatically when you edit the document. You should be able to easily [disable such replacements](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Turning_Off_AutoCorrect) globally, but I would instead recommend correcting the document or system locale so that useful replacements like typographic quotes and the em dash already mentioned can be inserted automatically.

Comment: Weird though that it does this when opening a file (not only when typing). That would annoy me a lot...

Comment: Any Idea where to look for the auto"correct" in Firefox?

Comment: There isn't any, as far as I know. Possibly a browser or desktop plugin would do this, but I'm not aware of any (and I've been using Firefox on Linux for many years).